# Github page is not showing up after 3 hours

Tags: github

i have uploaded my files to github 3 hours ago,still its not showing up.I know it takes time but i don't think it takes that long.

i am talking about this page [huge-psd-html.github.io](http://huge-psd-html.github.io/)

here is my repo [psd to html](https://github.com/wahidpolin/huge-psd-html.github.io)

Comment: Going to need some more information. Maybe a log of your command-line where you did a git push?

Comment: On the page it says the files were uploaded 3 hours ago and I see all of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your username is `wahidpolin` and you created a repository named `wahidpolin.github.io`, your website will be (and is) available at [`http://wahidpolin.github.io`](http://wahidpolin.github.io).

If you want to have your website online at `huge-psd-html.github.io`, you should create an organization named `huge-psd-html` and a repository named `huge-psd-html.github.io` and push there the content of your website.

Currently it's showing 404 because there is no such website.

Comment: solved the problem by myself,thnx anyway for your answer.People who didn't understand my question neg repped me without any reason

Comment: @WahidPolin You're welcome. Upvoted it and other questions by you. `:-)` I know the feeling to be downvoted. `:-D`